# error using cocoapods. updated Cocoapods now it ain't working?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

This morning while I was trying to install an SDK into my project, as I was on the terminal installing the cocoa pods, An update appeared saying it was a pre-release and it wanted me to test it, so well I installed the update now I got an error trying to use the cocoa pod function!

```
          ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
```

I have tried to uninstall then re-install but nothing is working, I been having this problem since midday but couldn't find nothing that has helped.

also saying there is no such file or directory when I was trying to install the pod file. Been trying to fix this all morning but not having any luck, Tried to downgrade my software as I am on El Capitan but wasn't able to do that either.

Answer (score 1):

try this in terminal

```
 sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```